# running Chrome in headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

To run **chrome in headless mode**, I did

> alias chrome="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\
>   Chrome"
>
> chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu --headless

in console, But, I got this error,

> [0305/140111.481537:ERROR:xattr.cc(64)] setxattr
>   org.chromium.crashpad.database.initialized on file
>   /var/folders/m3/92mmh21n0cx4ppf8c3bcns38hd4_kk/T/: Operation not
>   permitted (1) [0305/140111.484254:ERROR:xattr.cc(64)] setxattr
>   org.chromium.crashpad.database.initialized on file
>   /var/folders/m3/92mmh21n0cx4ppf8c3bcns38hd4_kk/T/: Operation not
>   permitted (1) [0305/140111.484254:INFO:crashpad_client_mac.cc(292)]
>   restarting handler in 0.983s
>   [0305/140111.513641:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1009)] Lost
>   UI shared context. [0305/140111.513709:ERROR:instance.cc(49)] Unable
>   to locate service manifest for metrics
>   [0305/140111.513733:ERROR:service_manager.cc(890)] Failed to resolve
>   service name: metrics [0305/140111.514229:ERROR:socket_posix.cc(142)]
>   bind() returned an error, errno=48: Address already in use (48)
>
> DevTools listening on
>   ws://[::1]:9222/devtools/browser/c46563ca-1891-48bd-bdd6-e6122f3f3b5d
>   [0305/140112.484141:ERROR:xattr.cc(64)] setxattr
>   org.chromium.crashpad.database.initialized on file
>   /var/folders/m3/92mmh21n0cx4ppf8c3bcns38hd4_kk/T/: Operation not
>   permitted (1) [0305/140112.484641:INFO:crashpad_client_mac.cc(292)]
>   restarting handler in 0.985s [0305/140113.489618:ERROR:xattr.cc(64)]
>   setxattr org.chromium.crashpad.database.initialized on file
>   /var/folders/m3/92mmh21n0cx4ppf8c3bcns38hd4_kk/T/: Operation not
>   permitted (1) [0305/140113.490274:INFO:crashpad_client_mac.cc(292)]
>   restarting handler in 0.979s [0305/140114.484881:ERROR:xattr.cc(64)]
>   setxattr org.chromium.crashpad.database.initialized on file
>   /var/folders/m3/92mmh21n0cx4ppf8c3bcns38hd4_kk/T/: Operation not
>   permitted (1) [0305/140114.485349:INFO:crashpad_client_mac.cc(292)]
>   restarting handler in 0.985s [0305/140115.489188:ERROR:xattr.cc(64)]
>   setxattr org.chromium.crashpad.database.initialized on file
>   /var/folders/m3/92mmh21n0cx4ppf8c3bcns38hd4_kk/T/: Operation not
>   permitted (1) [0305/140115.489638:INFO:crashpad_client_mac.cc(292)]
>   restarting handler in 0.985s

I also tried,

> /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
>   --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu --headless

but I got same error.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

**UPDATE 3/6**
I checked the solution on my own MacBook and it worked.

---

I encounter the same issue today, and after searching some document, I suspect it's due to the [SIP(System Integrity Protection) feature](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193379) in MacOS, with that restrict, you can't modify the files under `/var` folder even you have the root privilege.

So [here](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-turn-off-mac-os-x-system-integrity-protection-rootless-3638975/) is the way to disable that feature:

1. Turn off your Mac (Apple > Shut Down).
2. Hold down Command-R and press the Power button. Keep holding Command-R until the Apple logo appears.
3. Wait for OS X to boot into the OS X Utilities window.
4. Choose Utilities > Terminal.
5. Enter csrutil disable.
6. Enter reboot.

Comment: You **really** should not be disabling System Integrity, this is a significant security risk and will cause you some serious problems in the future.

Comment: **Very** bad idea.

Comment: Savagry! Be sure and NOT do this if you are on a work computer.

Answer (score 34):

I got the answer from [Chrome crashpad crashes on xattr](https://superuser.com/questions/1292863/chrome-crashpad-crashes-on-xattr/1307573)

Just provide a different directory for "crash dumps" when starting Chrome, like this:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu --headless --crash-dumps-dir=/tmp
```

Comment: For clarity, solved with this extra flag: `--crash-dumps-dir=/tmp`

Answer (score 4):

add the following command flags

```
--disk-cache-dir=/tmp --user-data-dir=/tmp --crash-dumps-dir=/tmp
```

eg.

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot --disk-cache-dir=/tmp --user-data-dir=/tmp --crash-dumps-dir=/tmp http://m.baidu.com
```

For more command-line flags, see [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2Fchromium%2Fsrc%2Fheadless%2Fapp%2Fheadless_shell_switches.cc)

Comment: Or disable crash logging altogether? Using --disable-crash-reporter (found via your link)

Comment: I prefer the `--disable-crash-reporter` way since I don't need crash report in headless mode.